# Forms Authentication issue with Context.rewritePath on Windows 2012 R2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-8

I am having an issue with asp.net context.RewritePath() since we have moved to Windows Server 2012 R2.  (note this might also be an issue in Windows 2012).

In the Application_BeginRequest() we rewrite the URL /custom to a specific customer's folder structure like /customer/1/images

In order to do this we have to have .Net process static files for us.  We enabled that with the following in web.config:

We also use Forms Authentication for authentication.  This uses an MVC filter on the controllers.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Authentication/LogOn" />
</authentication>
```

This works perfect in Windows 2008 R2 and the images that are stored in the path /custom/images/logo.png show up perfect when nobody has been logged in.

However in Windows 2012 R2 we cannot get any images to appear unless a user has been authenticated.  It always prompts for the login page.  If I directly go to the path /customer/1/images.logo.png it will return the image fine without being authenticated.

There has been some change that is causing this to now always require authentication.

I have tried all of the various settings  in the web.config like:

```
<location path="custom">
<system.web>
<authorization>
<allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

but none of that has helped either.

The entire rest of the application works fine and the rewrite itself works great once people are authenticated.